Python seems to return incorrect data length for NULL value from a Pandas dataframe
I am trying to find the longest value and its length from a column in a Pandas dataframe.
This column holds country codes which are strictly 2 charterers without any empty strings or spaces, but data could be missing.
For example, data looks like this:
col
US
RU
None

My codes look like this:
max_data_len = df_copy[col].astype(str).str.len().max()
longest_value = df_copy[col].iloc[df_copy[col].astype(str).str.len().idxmax()]
print(max_data_len)
print(longest_value)

While the output is
4
None

where I am expecting the results to be
2
'US'

Could you suggest what else I need to do to achieve the above, and also is there a way to return the longest value and its length in a single line?

When you convert it using astype(str), it coerces None to the string "None".  To avoid this, you can fill with an empty string.
max_data_len = df_copy[col].fillna('').str.len().max()
longest_value = df_copy[col].iloc[df_copy[col].fillna('').str.len().idxmax()]


Thanks, James! It turns out some of my columns are numeric type so I have to keep the astype(str) after fillna(''), then this works df_copy[col].fillna('').astype(str).str.len().max() Any opportunities to optimize this and in finding the location though?

you can achieve this by filtering out the None values, then affect it to a new dataframe, before computing the length.
like this:
filtered_df = df['col'].dropna()
#the length of the longest value
max_data_len = filtered_df.astype(str).str.len().max()
#the longest value
longest_value = filtered_df.iloc[filtered_df.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()]

And to do it in one line you can do
max_data_len, longest_value = filtered_df.astype(str).str.len().max(), filtered_df.iloc[filtered_df.astype(str).str.len().idxmax()]

